# Can I do my testament as a video on a social network in France?

Tags: internet, france, wills, probate

Imagine if I do my testament as a video and post it in private on a social network. Will this video be legally usable and will a notary be able to force the company to give him the video?

Is there any things I can do to make my video valid (be facing the camera, showing ID Card, add subtitles...)?

Comment: Wills differ greatly between jurisdictions. In which country does this take place?

Comment: Post edited. I'm curious so i'll be thankful if you can answer for another jurisdiction.

Answer (score 3):

## No.

In most civil-law countries, including France, a testament must follow very specific forms. It must be either handwritten (holographic will) or confirmed by a notary (authentic will, mystic will). Both possibilities preclude wills as video.